# Turn off page builder for product description field

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to disable page builder for product description field? I know there are articles how to remove from category description, but I didn't find for the product description, I tried to do it myself (result below) but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content" sortOrder="10">
        <container name="container_description" sortOrder="10">
            <field name="description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>
                        <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

Open the attribute from Magento admin, then select **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** dropdown
[image]

Save it.

**Alternative solution:**

If you want to programmatically modify this behavior, then create a plugin for **vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav/WysiwygConfigDataProcessor.php**, and return the following code from your plugin.

```
$wysiwygConfigData['is_pagebuilder_enabled'] = false;
```

Will disable the page builder

Answer (score 1):

Please go to admin panel

Store => Attributes => Product

[image]

Click on description after open new page see below
[image]

change page builder to text editor

after apply below commands.

```
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

after show final image product admin

[image]